# Is there an accepted method by which a C# application can generate a list of SQL stored procedures which satisfy certain criteria?

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures

Fellow programmers,

I am writing a C# application which will interact with a SQL database to retrieve information about Production processes.

**THE BACKGROUND**

Each singular Production process has a unique integer StageID.

**All** processes write common information (PASS/FAIL status etc) to a `ProcessMaster` table.

Some processes write additional data to custom tables, and they use the primary key from the `ProcessMaster` to form the relationship.

I am in the position of writing some stored procedures to get the data. There's a standard stored procedure which just gets `ProcessMaster` data based on `StageID`.  This works for all processes.

But, on an individual basis, I write a custom stored procedure for those processes which have additional data in their own tables. In that case I do a table join in the stored procedure so that I get back the standard `ProcessMaster` data *and* the additional data.

An example of a process which has the custom stored procedure would be a measurement system which, in addition to storing PASS/FAIL and standard `ProcessMaster` data, also stores a bunch of measurement results in its own table.

**THE PROBLEM**

I am writing a C# application which provides an interface to all this. I want the user to select a process, and then be able to fetch data for it based on a date range.

If the selected Stage is one which has `ProcessMaster` *and* custom data, I want there to be an option to select whether to include only `ProcessMaster` or all available data.

**CURRENT IDEA**

My current idea is to use some naming convention with the stored procedures.  This way I can discover them at runtime and handle them in my C# application appropriately.

If/when future stored procedures are made available (e.g. for a new process), then provided that the established naming convention is followed then those processes would become immediately available for enumeration in my C# data interface application.

**SUGGESTIONS?**

I am interested in programming concept answers from StackOverflow users who regularly interface with SQL in their applications. Am I missing anything? Is there a better way to accomplish this goal? For example: is it possible to include meta data inside the stored procedure itself which I could discover at runtime?

Comment: "Provided that the established naming convention is followed" = point of failure. Why not just have a registry of some sort (e.g. table) that lists all the available processes? Your application can then rely on that to know what's out there. That registry can also include meta data that can allow you to handle each process appropriately. That being said, this is a question that lends itself to opinionated answers so I don't think it belongs here.

Comment: @juanr using a naming convention to wire things up is a commonplace practice.  It's called "convention over configuration."

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I argee, but: As JuanR mentioned, a "configuration table" would offer the possibility to add meta data to handle the data. That is also the reason, that I would prefer to create different implementations (like plug-ins) to display or process for different data.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Yes, but I am personally not very fond of that approach for situations like this where developers are involved anyways. It lends itself to potential breaking points like someone accidentally creating a stored procedure with the naming convention, causing a problem in the program. I also would be inclined to use a plugin architecture as mentioned by H.G. Sandhagen but it may be overkill for something like this.